# Currency format in DataGridView  in windows application

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatting

i am unable to show currency format on DataGridView.
Can you people look this code.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
                                   DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    objPreview.dataGridView1.Columns["Debit"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
    objPreview.dataGridView1.Columns["Credit"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype for `Debit`, `Credit` in your datasource ?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Comment: Debit, Credit are Decimal type

Comment: Can you try assigning the format before the datasource assignment

Comment: is that work for you ???

Answer (score 4):

if it is windows form than write this code before you are binding data to the grid...something as below in the form consturctor...

```
public Form1()
{
   this.dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
}
```

if its ASP.Net
try something like `DataFormatString="{0:c}"`

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price/Unit" 
                DataField="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" 
                DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
```

Comment: I think this is related to winform

Comment: Hmmm .. `DefaultCellStyle` might help in deciding that

Comment: @V4Vendetta - i updated answer for this he has to write line of the code in consturctor before binding data of grid ...

Comment: An important Note when you use this kind of format the value assigned to the cell MUST also be a numeric type otherwise it is not applied (happened to me in a case where the grid is more dynamic and values are serialized as strings and restored later, it took some time before realizing this happened for me)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this

```
objPreview.dataGridView1.Columns["Debit"].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
objPreview.dataGridView1.Columns["Credit"].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
```

Comment: i need currency format. i hope this is not relevant code for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check ( breakpoint or something ) that DataBindingComplete event is fired . So at least we know its not that

( edited ) 
So if its fired check this maybe it will help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4sab6f9

Maybe by creating a new style it will help

Comment: Event is firing but $ symbol is not adding to the values.

Comment: You should wait for the 50 mark to earn the comment privilege, else people might down vote as this ain't any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this for Windows Forms: (or its equivalent for WPF or ASP ,...)

```
yourColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#";

// And add below if you want
yourColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue= "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already binded your DataSource to the DataGridView, you can set your cell style by setting each cell format like:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  row.Cells["Debit"].Style.Format = "c";
  row.Cells["Credit"].Style.Format = "c";  
}
```

Make sure your value is numerical.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code @Pranay Rana suggested into the **CellFormatting** Event on the DataGridView:

```
private void NameOfYourGridGoesHere_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    this.NameOfYourGridGoesHere.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
}
```