# How to display currency sign in DataGridView that gets it data from a SQL server database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I'm using C# Winforms, and Microsoft SQL Server

This is how the data is filled

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridSrch.DataSource = dt;
    dv.Sort = "Item, Brand, Manufacturer, Car, Year, Price ASC ";
    dataGridSrch.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
    dataGridSrch.Columns[7].DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
    dataGridSrch.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    dataGridSrch.Columns[8].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    dataGridSrch.Rows[scrollIndex].Selected = true;
    dataGridSrch.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollPos;
    typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,
                                       dataGridSrch, new object[] { true });
}
```

Or add this code, from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-default-cell-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

```
DataGridViewCellStyle currencyCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
currencyCellStyle.Format = "C";
currencyCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
dataGridSrch.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle = currencyCellStyle;
```

Also added the formatting in the `DataBindingComplete` Event

[image: Column need to have currency sign]

The column format didn't show the currency format. The column design from the SQL Server, Price column has a `DataType` of `decimal(18,2)`. If I change it to `money` or `smallmoney`.

[image]

I have been reading these similar question but still no luck.

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715276/currency-format-in-datagridview-in-windows-application), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026196/datagridview-how-to-set-the-currency-format-for-a-single-column-only)

EDIT:

This is my `CellFormatting` Event

```
private void dataGridSrch_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Value = e.Value.ToString().ToUpper();
        if (dataGridSrch.DataSource != null)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridSrch.Columns["Price"].Index && e.Value != null)
            {
                e.CellStyle.Format = "C";          //or "C2", both are not working
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; //working
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't the answer to question 2 work for you? You could also try the CellFormatting Event.

Comment: Forgot that one. I already have formatting for that event. Ill update the question. I also dont know. I have deleted the `DataGridView` and created a new one. Still no currency is displayed.

Comment: That's not how you use the event, see the example here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Crowcoder since I'm trying to format the value to have a currency symbol I used `e.CellStyle.Format = "C";`, but it didn't work. So I tried changing the color if it is checking the whole column. And yes it did change the color of the column values that are not `null`, this is for testing. Did I use the `Format` wrong?

Comment: If by currency format you mean the expected output for `2` is  `$2.00`, then it's enough to set the format this way: `dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";`.

Comment: I have already did that, but no currency is shown. Based on the Question 2 link in the question.

Comment: Please consider posting [MCVE]. The question in the current format is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Also when you want to mention someone in a comment, try using @ and then mention the name. Like this `@Jepher`, otherwise they will not be informed that you have posted a comment.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, yes it is alike, but the it doesn't solve my format. That is why I'm puzzled here since why it is not displaying its currency

Comment: Creating MCVE for this problem is really easy. For example I used `"SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2), 123.45678) AS Column1"` as command and then load data. Then after I set `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` I set `dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";` and everything worked well. I didn't change `DataGridView` at designer at all and used all default settings, without adding any column manually.

Comment: The reason that I closed the question as duplicate is because in the current format it's an exact duplicate. If for any reason you have a problem setting the format for column you should be able to share a [MCVE] to reproduce the problem. Unless no one can share any help with you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It still didn't show any format, even format other than `C2`. But thanks for saying the `CONVERT()` in `SELECT` statement, it did gave me an idea. I have solved it using `FORMAT()` in `SELECT` statement.

Comment: It would be better if you can solve the problem at presentation layer rather than solving it in database layer. Anyway, it's good that you could solve the problem.